# getImage.jsp giving the same image for different byte[] attribute value. Any Suggestion?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Trying to generate Image for the byte array attribute. But same image
getting generated for all item.getItem_image(). Any Suggestion?

home.jsp

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
    <c:set var="item_image" value="${item.getItem_image()}" scope="session"/>           
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getImage"
                        width="130px" />
</c:forEach>
```

home.jsp

```
byte byteArray[] = (byte[])session.getAttribute("item_image");
            response.setContentType("image/gif");
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            os.write(byteArray);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
```

Comment: It appears you're getting the same image every time from the session.  Is there any other code?

Comment: for img src use item_image instead of getImage.Verify if it gets u a unique path.